# Is it possible to migrate down from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint portal that has been developed on SharePoint 2016 , I ask if it's possible to move content database to SharePoint 2013 environment?

I appreciate any advice/ suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This impossible for more reasons

- Like upgrading down, Microsoft sees no meaning for migration down.
- If you tried to restore a content database 2016 backup you will get

> This content database has a schema version which is not supported in
>   this farm

For SharePoint 2016 Database schema is start with `16.x.xxx.xxx`
For SharePoint 2013 Database schema is start with `15.x.xxx.xxx`

Also, Migration from the same SharePoint Edition you will get Schema issue if you don't match the Configuration database version of destination farm to be the same as the source farm before you take a backup of content database from source farm

For more details,You can also check [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)

Also, to achieve your target, You have only two option

- Upgrade the destination farm.
- Repeat your work on the destination farm from scratch!.

Hope it helps you

Comment: I tried to do this and I got what exactly you have mentioned, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.  They have different schemas, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not Out-Of-The-Box, but 3rd party tools like [ShareGate](http://en.share-gate.com/migrate-to-sharepoint-2016) might be able to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as per the limitations of product. You are going back to one version even within same version level you can't back to previous build number( uninstall the cu).

If you just want to move the content then that is possible either use the manual approach or 3rd party tools(which support the moving content between sharepoint farm from lower version to higher or higher to lower)

But if it is customization and solutions then your mileage vary as not all 3rd party tools support customization migration. Also if you build on higher level which include the latest feature and if you go back to lower version where these features not available will cause the issue.